# Merging 2 CSV files based on matching values on common column and writing the combined new set into a new CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, sys

I'm trying to use Pandas to merge the content of two separate CSV files based
on one column that exists in both CSV files.

First CSV file:
This file contains more than 500 records, and the format of this file is:

```
Computer_Name   Purchase_Date        Vendor           Is_Virtual      Is_Patched
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Computer_1      4-11-2018           Dell                 NaN            NaN
Computer_2      5-5-2016            HP                   Yes            NaN
Computer_3      1-05-2015           IBM                  NaN            NaN
```

Second CSV:
This file contains one column and may include fewer records. The "Computer_Name" column may contain system names in a mix of upper and lower case formats. Additionally, the "Computer_Name" may include the system's domain name (i.e., "company.com").

```
Computer_Name
--------------------
Computer_1.company.com
Computer_3
Computer_5.company.com
```

I'm trying to change the values of the "Is_Patched" column in every row to "Yes" if the "Computer_Name" matches in both CSV files for that row.

The following is what I have so far and it seems to work:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import sys

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

assets = pd.read_csv(r"C:\AssetsFile.csv")          #First CSV file
references = pd.read_csv(r"C:\ReferenceFile.csv")   #Second CSV file

assets['Computer_Name'] = assets['Computer_Name'].str.lower()

assets['Computer_Name'] = assets['Computer_Name'].str.split('.').str[0]

references['Computer_Name'] = references['Computer_Name'].str.lower()

references['Computer_Name'] = references['Computer_Name'].str.split('.').str[0]

assets.merge(references, on='Computer_Name')
```

However, I cannot figure-out how to insert value "Yes" into the "Is_patched" column when there is a match in both CSV files for "Computer_Name" for that row
and write the new Pandas set into a new CSV file.

I'm hoping someone can give me a good direction on how to approach this problem.
Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We first split your `computer_name` column in your second dataframe by `.` and keep the first part.

Then we check with `Series.isin` if the computer_name from the second dataframe is present in the first dataframe.

We use `np.where` to conditionally fill in `Yes` or `No` when there's a match:

```
s = references['Computer_Name'].str.split('.').str[0]

assets['Is_Patched'] = np.where(assets['Computer_Name'].isin(s), 'Yes', 'No')
```

```
  Computer_Name Purchase_Date Vendor Is_Virtual Is_Patched
0    Computer_1     4-11-2018   Dell        NaN        Yes
1    Computer_2      5-5-2016     HP        Yes         No
2    Computer_3     1-05-2015    IBM        NaN        Yes
```

Comment: Thank you for this information! However, I'm getting "NameError: name 'np' is not defined" error when I run it.

Comment: `import numpy as np` @Planet-9 above this code. Just like `import pandas as pd`

Comment: I should include that module before I post it back; sorry. Thank you for your help!